# Create Folder after profile.php/

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm not sure what I need to search, since I don't know what it's called of even if I describe It right, so please don't tell me I didn't do my research, I did. I honestly did.

How can I make it so that a .php like *profile.php can redirect to a folder. For example:

profile.php = example.com/profile.php/ = example.php/user/ = then a folder = example.com/user/info/

I have it so that the $_GET['user'] redirects the profile.php?username=$1 to "Brian" via .htaccess. But is it possible to get it to like profile.php/folder?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a file and a directory, and maybe read about `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Comment: Those are not folders IMO, they are just part of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`